# What is the error in the input card codes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What is the error in the input card codes, the + - buttons work fine, but the value of the input is not added to the basket with the product, only one product is added
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

```js
  var shoppingCart = (function() {
   
   // =============================
   // Private methods and propeties
   // =============================
   cart = [];
   // Constructor
   function Item( name, price, count, image) {
     this.name = name;
     this.price = price;
     this.count= count;
     this.image = image
   }
   
   // Save cart
   function saveCart() {
     localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
   }
   
     // Load cart
   function loadCart() {
     cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
   }
   if (localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
     loadCart();
   }
   
  
   // =============================
   // Public methods and propeties
   // =============================
   var obj = {};
   
   // Add to cart
   obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count, image) {
     for(var item in cart) {
       if(cart[item].name === name) {
         cart[item].count ++;
         saveCart();
         return;
       }
     }
     var item = new Item(name, price, count, image);
     cart.push(item);
     saveCart();
   }
   // Set count from item
   obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
     for(var i in cart) {
       if (cart[i].name === name) {
         cart[i].count = count;
         break;
       }
     }
   };
   // Remove item from cart
   obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
       for(var item in cart) {
         if(cart[item].name === name) {
           cart[item].count --;
           if(cart[item].count === 0) {
             cart.splice(item, 1);
           }
           break;
         }
     }
     saveCart();
   }
  
   // Remove all items from cart
   obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
     for(var item in cart) {
       if(cart[item].name === name) {
         cart.splice(item, 1);
         break;
       }
     }
     saveCart();
   }
  
   // Clear cart
   obj.clearCart = function() {
     cart = [];
     saveCart();
   }
  
   // Count cart 
   obj.totalCount = function() {
     var totalCount = 0;
     for(var item in cart) {
       totalCount += cart[item].count;
     }
     return totalCount;
   }
  
   // Total cart
   obj.totalCart = function() {
     var totalCart = 0;
     for(var item in cart) {
       totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
     }
     return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
   }
  
   // List cart
   obj.listCart = function() {
     var cartCopy = [];
     for(i in cart) {
       item = cart[i];
       itemCopy = {};
       for(p in item) {
         itemCopy[p] = item[p];
  
       }
       itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
       cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
     }
     return cartCopy;
   }
  
   // cart : Array
   // Item : Object/Class
   // addItemToCart : Function
   // removeItemFromCart : Function
   // removeItemFromCartAll : Function
   // clearCart : Function
   // countCart : Function
   // totalCart : Function
   // listCart : Function
   // saveCart : Function
   // loadCart : Function
   return obj;
  })();
  
  
  // *****************************************
  // Triggers / Events
  // ***************************************** 
  // Add item
  $('.additem').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var name = $(this).data('name');
   var price = parseInt($(this).data('price'));
   var image  = $(this).parents("div.card").find(".card-img-top").attr('src')
   shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1 ,image);
   displayCart();
  });
  
  // Clear items
  $('.clear-cart-items').click(function() {
   shoppingCart.clearCart();
   displayCart();
  });
  
  
  function displayCart() {
  
   var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
   var output = "";
   for(var i in cartArray) {
        output += "<tr class='cartTable'>"
       +  "<td><img src='" + cartArray[i].image + "' style='width:150px;'></td>" 
       + "<td class='TableTitle'>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>"
       + "<td>" + cartArray[i].price + "</td>"
       + "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>"
       + "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
       + "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>"
       + "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">X</button></td>"
       + " = " 
       + "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" 
       +  "</tr>"; 
       
   }
   $('.show-cart').html(output);
   $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
   $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
  }
  
  
  // Delete item button
  
  $('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
   var name = $(this).data('name')
   shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
   displayCart();
  })
   
   //These are the codes of the internal input, the input of the cart
   //This input works well and the buttons are as well. When you 
  click 
   on each button, the value is provided
  // -1
  $('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function (event) {
   var name = $(this).data('name')
   shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
   displayCart();
  })
  
  
  // +1
  $('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
   var name = $(this).data('name')
   shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
   displayCart();
  })
  
  
  // Item count input
  $('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var count = Number($(this).val());
   shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
   displayCart();
  });
  
  
  displayCart();
  
  
//These are the codes of the external input, the input of the card
//here the buttons + - work fine but the input value is not added to the cart, only one product is added, even if the input value is 10
  
  function increaseCount(a, b) {
    var input = b.nextElementSibling;
    var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    input.value = value;
    displayCart();
  }
  
  function decreaseCount(a, b) {
    var input = b.previousElementSibling;
    var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
    if (value > 1) {
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value--;
      input.value = value;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="ourproducts">


  <div class="card" >
      <img class="card-img-top"  src="images/img/1.png" alt="Product Name" data-hook="product-image">
     <div class="setproprice">
       <div class="proprice">
          <span class="spanpropreice1">Offer</span><span class="card-text">1.50</span>
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="protext">
          <span>Germany</span>
          <h2 class="card-title"  >Product 1</h2>
           <span>weight</span>
           <span>tax</span>
      </div>
      <fieldset class="card-block"  data-hook="product-item-quantity-counter" 
      aria-label="select quantity" dir="rtl" data-error="false">

     <div>
       <button  class="plus-item" data-name=`cartArray[i].name`  onClick='increaseCount(event, this)' ><span  data-name="cartArray[i].name" class="material-icons plus-item">
           add
           </span></button>

           <input type="number"  class="item-count"  value="1"   data-name="cartArray[i].name"  min="1" max="20" step="1" >

           <button class="minus-item"  data-name="cartArray[i].name" onClick='decreaseCount(event, this)'  value="1" ><span data-name="cartArray[i].name" class="material-icons minus-item">
               remove
               </span></button>
     </div>
      </fieldset>
      <button class="additem"  data-name="Product"  data-price="2.00+'€'" onclick="addNew()"> 
       <label class="addItemLabel">Add Item</label> <span class="material-icons AddItemCartImage">
          shopping_cart</span>
          <span class="material-icons fff">shopping_cart</span>
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag bbb" aria-hidden="true"  style="font-size: 15px;"></i>      
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the image being stored? Where is it coming from?

Comment: the image comeing from images file, I have it from the main file @kmoser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I fixed the issue, I also changed all vars to let or const to ensure data values don't get manipulated. You just needed to pass the count though to the add basket method

```
    let count = parseInt($(this).parents("div.card").find(".item-count").val());
    shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, count, image);
```

then in the basket method needed to either use the passed-in value or add 1 to the count for the + icon when the item is in the basket

```
cart[item].count += count ||  1
```

I fixed a few other minor things too

see: https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHume/h7wabuLr/ (the below won't run because SO doesn't allow localStorage in their code runners

```js
const shoppingCart = (function() {

  // =============================
  // Private methods and properties
  // =============================
  let cart = [];
  // Constructor
  class Item {
    constructor(name, price, count, image) {
      this.name = name;
      this.price = price;
      this.count = count;
      this.image = image;
    }
  }

  // Save cart
  function saveCart() {
    localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }

  // Load cart
  function loadCart() {
     cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
    loadCart();
  }


  // =============================
  // Public methods and properties
  // =============================
  const obj = {};

  // Add to cart
  obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count, image) {
  debugger
    for (let item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart[item].count += count ||  1
        saveCart();
        return;
      }
    }
    let item = new Item(name, price, count, image);
    cart.push(item);
    saveCart();
  }
  // Set count from item
  obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
    for (let i in cart) {
      if (cart[i].name === name) {
        cart[i].count = count;
        break;
      }
    }
  };
  // Remove item from cart
  obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
    for (let item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart[item].count--;
        if (cart[item].count === 0) {
          cart.splice(item, 1);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    saveCart();
  }

  // Remove all items from cart
  obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
    for (let item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart.splice(item, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    saveCart();
  }

  // Clear cart
  obj.clearCart = function() {
    cart = [];
    saveCart();
  }

  // Count cart 
  obj.totalCount = function() {
    let totalCount = 0;
    for (let item in cart) {
      totalCount += cart[item].count;
    }
    return totalCount;
  }

  // Total cart
  obj.totalCart = function() {
    let totalCart = 0;
    for (let item in cart) {
      totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
    }
    return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
  }

  // List cart
  obj.listCart = function() {
    let cartCopy = [];
    for (let i in cart) {
      let item = cart[i];
      itemCopy = {};
      for (let p in item) {
        itemCopy[p] = item[p];
      }
      itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
      cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
    }
    return cartCopy;
  }

  // cart : Array
  // Item : Object/Class
  // addItemToCart : Function
  // removeItemFromCart : Function
  // removeItemFromCartAll : Function
  // clearCart : Function
  // countCart : Function
  // totalCart : Function
  // listCart : Function
  // saveCart : Function
  // loadCart : Function
  return obj;
})();


// *****************************************
// Triggers / Events
// ***************************************** 
// Add item
$('.additem').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let name = $(this).data('name');
  let price = parseInt($(this).data('price'));
  let image = $(this).parents("div.card").find(".card-img-top").attr('src')
  let count = parseInt($(this).parents("div.card").find(".item-count").val());
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, count, image);
  displayCart();
});

// Clear items
$('.clear-cart-items').click(function() {
  shoppingCart.clearCart();
  displayCart();
});


function displayCart() {
  let cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
  let output = "";
  for (let i in cartArray) {
    output += "<tr class='cartTable'>" +
      "<td><img src='" + cartArray[i].image + "' style='width:150px;'></td>" +
      "<td class='TableTitle'>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + cartArray[i].price + "</td>" +
      "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>-</button>" +
      "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>" +
      "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>+</button></div></td>" +
      "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>X</button></td>" +
      " = " +
      "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" +
      "</tr>";

  }
  $('.show-cart').html(output);
  $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
  $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
}


// Delete item button

$('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
  let name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
  displayCart();
})

//These are the codes of the internal input, the input of the cart
//This input works well and the buttons are as well. When you 
//click 
// each button, the value is provided
// -1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
  let name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
  displayCart();
})


// +1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
debugger;
  let name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
  displayCart();
})


// Item count input
$('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
  let name = $(this).data('name');
  let count = Number($(this).val());
  shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
  displayCart();
});


displayCart();


//These are the codes of the external input, the input of the card
//here the buttons + - work fine but the input value is not added to the cart, only one product is added, even if the input value is 10

function increaseCount(a, b) {
  let input = b.nextElementSibling;
  let value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  input.value = value;
  displayCart();
}

function decreaseCount(a, b) {
  debugger;
  let input = b.previousElementSibling;
  let value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  if (value > 1) {
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    input.value = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ourproducts">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" width="50px" height="50px" src="https://pngpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/uploads_guava_guava_PNG60.png" alt="product-img" data-hook="product-image">
    <div class="setproprice">
      <div class="proprice">
        <span class="spanpropreice1">Offer</span><span class="card-text">1.50</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="protext">
      <span>Germany</span>
      <h2 class="card-title">Product-name</h2>
      <span>weight</span>
      <span>tax</span>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="card-block" data-hook="product-item-quantity-counter" aria-label="select the quantity" dir="rtl" data-error="false">

      <div>
        <button class="plus-item" data-name=`cartArray[i].name` onClick='increaseCount(event, this)'><span data-name="cartArray[i].name" class="material-icons plus-item">
            add
          </span></button>

        <input type="number" class="item-count" value="1" data-name="cartArray[i].name" min="1" max="20" step="1">

        <button class="minus-item" data-name="cartArray[i].name" onClick='decreaseCount(event, this)' value="1"><span data-name="cartArray[i].name" class="material-icons minus-item">
            remove
          </span></button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button class="additem" data-name="tne name of the product" data-price="2.00"> Add Item<span class="material-icons">
        shopping_cart
      </span></button>
  </div>

</div>
<table class="show-cart">

</table>
<div>
  <p>
  </p>
  <container>Total amount: <item class="total-cart">0
    </item>
  </container>
  <p></p>
  <container>Number of Items: <item class="total-count">0
    </item>
  </container>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Great, I was finally able thanks to you, I tried to follow you on the other site https://jsfiddle.net/ but I couldn't .. I am very grateful to you .. Thank you very much

Comment: that's ok I'm glad I was able to help, I'm on github but honestly I'm not sure I'm worth following I'm not that good a developer, I get by though ;)

Comment: hello
You helped me unbelievably, I tried a lot in these codes, but I could not find a solution alone.. You really deserve to follow... If you have a page on Facebook or a YouTube channel, write me here.. Greetings

Comment: thanks if i can help  someone that's payment enough for me ;)

Comment: Hello Mister Patrick Hume how are you? Can you solve the puzzle here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73080690/how-can-i-hide-the-list

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I was away, I have posted an answer on the link above that you gave, I hope it helps

Comment: thank you very much
I have seen him

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code a bit to pass it though, a bit like the following...

```
function Item( name, price, count, image) {
     this.name = name;
     this.price = price;
     this.count= count;
     this.image = image
   }
```

```
obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count, image) {
     for(var item in cart) {
       if(cart[item].name === name) {
         cart[item].count ++;
         saveCart();
         return;
       }
     }
     var item = new Item(name, price, count, image);
     cart.push(item);
     saveCart();
   }
```

```
$('.additem').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var name = $(this).data('name');
   var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
   var image  = $(this).parents("div.ourproducts").find(".card-img-top").attr('src')
   shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1 ,image );
   displayCart();
  });
```

then just add the image into your displayCart string append

(I have updated the below line )

```
 "<td><img src='" + cartArray[i].image + "' alt='product-img' data-hook='product-image'></td>" +
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you that you tried to help me, but unfortunately the product image did not appear in the basket, just place an image but not the product image, you can click on this link and see the image

Comment: think you forgot to post the link or add the image in your comment there...ok so  is the image you want added to the basket is it the one from     <img class="card-img-top"  src="images/tomaten.png" alt="product-img" data-hook="product-image">   ?

Comment: sorry, this is the link of the image 
https://b.top4top.io/p_2388tor4m1.png

Comment: yes, this is the html tag 
<img class="card-img-top"  src="images/tomaten.png" alt="product-image" data-hook="product-image">

Comment: ah ok so it is adding the image, if you use the inspect elemnt what is the src of that image in the html please ?

Comment: Here is a link to the image showing the source of the image

https://www10.0zz0.com/2022/07/16/20/922980189.png
The source as shown in the element inspection is <img src="images/tomaten.pngalt='product-img'" data-hook="product-image">

Comment: AH I see now, that's my bad, in the original answer there was a typo, I have updated the answer above just looking for the line of code below where it says "(I have updated the below line )"  , what its doing is not adding a space between   
 src=images/tomaten.png    and     alt=product-img    and didn't add quotes around each part, the rendered HTML in the source needs to match the html of the original image e.g.   <img class="card-img-top" src="images/tomaten.png" alt="product-image" data-hook="product-image">,   try the modified line i posted above that should fix it for you

Comment: Excellent, the picture has been added to the basket, but if you add any other product, what appears is the first picture, not the original product picture. You can see the pictures in order

Comment: pic 1
https://www4.0zz0.com/2022/07/16/22/770214731.png
pic 2
https://www4.0zz0.com/2022/07/16/22/414104386.png
pic 3
https://www4.0zz0.com/2022/07/16/22/619748909.png

Comment: Does that mean it's working now?

Comment: Now the images appear in the basket, but unfortunately if you try to add another product, only the image of the first product appears

Comment: pic 1 
www4.0zz0.com/2022/07/16/22/770214731.png 
pic 2
 www4.0zz0.com/2022/07/16/22/414104386.png 
pic 3 
www4.0zz0.com/2022/07/16/22/619748909.png

Comment: i think i know why but ill need to test locally, i think either a variable is not been reset properly or   $(this).parents("div.ourproducts").find(".card-img-top").attr('src') is not referencing the right image the second time, if you debug this line what value dose it give in the console.log ? Im trying to set up your example locally again, i did it so easily last time but cant remember how and this time having issues getting to run locally...ill get back to you with an answer ASAP but if you can debug that line and tell me what value it is that would help alot

Comment: I was able to show the pictures of all the products with a small change which is
  var image = $(this).parents("div.card").find(".card-img-top").attr('src')
instead of ("div.ourproducts")
Now the original product image appears, which is added to the basket.
https://www11.0zz0.com/2022/07/17/04/136878939.png

Comment: I have a problem shown in the pictures, if you can help me again,
The external input that is in the card works, but its value is not added to the basket. When you click add to the cart, only one item is added, while the input in the cart works perfectly. Why then? Definitely an error in one of the codes
pic 1 https://www12.0zz0.com/2022/07/17/04/246326415.png
pic 2 https://www12.0zz0.com/2022/07/17/04/734624782.png

Comment: are you able to update your code above to include the new changes  with the code for the + and the - and the add please, it really help me to help work out whats going on

Comment: i posed an answer on the aforementioned above link for you

Comment: no problem, glad I was able to help

Comment: have replied although not sure how helpful I was sorry

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you asking. I don't have Facebook and I have no intention of ever joining it sorry so i cant see the link,s I would suggest keeping it simple and just having a join button to each one separately and checking out the FB API docs for there share button, there is a how-to guide there, I id put the link on the other post of yours but it got remove by SO so cant repost it sorry I can't help more, google is alwasy your friend

Comment: Hello, there is a misunderstanding .. I did not ask if you have Facebook, I wanted to know how to write, the Share link via messenger correctly, because I want to put this link on the site, and At the time, I did not know how to write it correctly, but now I finally managed Who wrote it..thank you

Comment: ah ok sorry for the miss understanding and glad you worked it out in the en sorry i couldn't help more, I did try but my answer got removed

Comment: I thank you very much, you are not late in helping me and always try to do what you can.. Thanks again

Comment: no problem any time :)

Comment: Mr. Patrick, how are you?
There is a new puzzle that needs to be solved, I know you are a genius.. Please follow the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73461027/how-to-save-the-data-entered-in-localstorage

Comment: it seems someone has already posted an answer for you ?

Comment: Indeed, but there is still a problem, which is in the codes of the search function ()
While typing data on the input box, the search result does not appear, but all previously recorded data are shown complete

Comment: the question has been removed?